# Getting Below Error while Implementing Validation in ajax call Mvc-4 Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-ajax

Following Error Occurred while submitting form to check validation

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

The Error Comes at this line of code

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#RegisterCustomerFrm");
```

any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your scripts definitions - clearly they are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not included this javascript "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js".Please include it.

Comment: Thanks for respondig but i have included both jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js but still getting this error

Comment: Have you include this <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes i have included this reference as well. i already mentioned it in the above comment.but issue is still there in validating

Comment: here are the files i include for this:    <script src="~/Content/UnifyTheme/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: change the position first include validate.min.js then include this js jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: thanks yes the trick works, same thing was suggested in another answer  and it worked. Thanks for your help..

Comment: well bro i have accepted it as answer but as i am new to this platform so my vote's are saved but will reflect your profile after i got 15 reputations.